# Problem related to tangents and normals of a curve.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-curves, applications

I 've been trying the both sums, while first one I've no clue how to start about in the second one I a getting stuck.

[1] The equation of the normal at any point $\theta$ on the curve $x=a \cos\theta+ a\theta \sin\theta$, $y =a\sin \theta - a\theta \cos\theta$ is always at a distance

(a) 2a unit from origin
(b) a unit from origin 
(c) $\frac{1}{2}$ unit from origin 
(d) None of these . 
And (b) is the correct answer given.
It is a MCQ.

[2] If the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ to the curve $x^3+y^3=a^3$ meets the curve again at $(x_1,y_1)$ , then $\frac {x_1}x_0+\frac{y_1}y_0$ is equal to what?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the questions correctly? In [1] you use "$x$" in two different senses.

Comment: I've edited it :) . Thank you .

Comment: How does the normal to a curve have a distance to the origin? The first question is unclear to me.

Comment: @Anthony -- I expect he means the normal line.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis & @ bubba I've written whatever was there in the book.

Comment: What is a MCQ??

Comment: Multiple Choice Question. Only a single option is correct out of the 4 I've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first one we need to find $dy/d\theta $ and then $dx/d\theta $. then we can exploit the fact that

$dy/dx$ = ($dy/d\theta $)/$(dx/d\theta $).

that gives the slope of the tangent ,

Now we know that the normal slope = $(-1)/(tangent  slope) $.

now the pt $x=a \cos\theta+ a\theta \sin\theta$,  $y =a\sin \theta - a\theta \cos\theta$ ,

We can use point slope formula to get the normal equation.
.
then we use some coordinate geometry basics that state that

perpendicular distance of $ax+by+c=0 $ from any point (x1, y1) =

```
          [mod{(a(x1)+b(y1)+c}]/ $\sqrt\{a^2 + b^2}$
```

given here that $(x1, y1) $ = (0,0) and the perpendicular distance is c , just substitute and you are done .
(done assuming the fact that you know the basics of differentiation and coordinate geometry)

Comment: for the second question , specify the step where you are not able to proceed further.

Comment: I can find the slope only of the curve. In the second question.

Comment: i hope you got the first one... now the second one. i will just give you a idea so that you can carry it forward.... yes the slope is found and then using the point slope formula , we can find the tangent equation. and then put Y= y1 and X = x1 and then proceed ... is the second one a mcq question?

Comment: Yeah both are MCQ